# How to Create a Google Sheets Script for Reporting 26-Week New Highs using GOOGLEFINANCE Function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I'm looking to use GoogleSheets to display ticker symbols and prices in real-time of stocks that have created new 26-week highs, i.e. today's highest trading price is greater than any trading price during the last 26-week period.

I think GoogleSheets's native GOOGLEFINANCE function allows this to be done for a 52-week trailing period (e.g. a formula comparing attributes "high52" against current day's "high").  The GOOGLEFINANCE function doesn't have an attribute for a 26-week period.

Does anyone have a script or template of one I can apply to retrieve a stock's highest traded price over a trailing 26-week period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll describe the process in stages. Here is a command that returns a table with high price on every day within the last 26 weeks:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","high",TODAY()-26*7,TODAY())
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|       Date        |   High   |
+-------------------+----------+
| 2/2/2015 16:00:00 | 533      |
| 2/3/2015 16:00:00 | 533.4    |
| ................. | .......  |
```

Since you only want the maximum of these numbers, let's add a `QUERY` selecting the maximum of the second column:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","high",TODAY()-26*7,TODAY()),"select max(Col2)")
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| max High |
+----------+
| 678.64   |
+----------+
```

This may be already good enough for your purposes. If you want to get rid of the column header "max High", end the query string with `label max(Col2) ''`:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","high",TODAY()-26*7,TODAY()),"select max(Col2) label max(Col2) ''")
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| 678.64   |
+----------+
```

Comment: Works brilliantly.  Great explanations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler and quicker solution is to use MAX() and INDEX() functions:

```
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","high",TODAY()-26*7,TODAY(),"WEEKLY"),0,2))
```