# How to Run a Query in GoogleSheets for New 26-Week Highs Using GOOGLEFINANCE Function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to run a query in GoogleSheets using the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function to pull down a list of stocks reaching new 26-week highs (limited to US companies or perhaps more simply US stock markets).

[A previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/how-to-create-a-google-sheets-script-for-reporting-26-week-new-highs-using-googl) resolved the issue of computing a specified stock's 26-week high price.  I'm seeking to create lists throughout the day of stocks creating new 26-week highs for the day.

I've looked for an `ImportHTML` function solution but [Google Finance Stock Screener](https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener) does not have produce such lists.

Can anyone advise how to create such a stock-screen query or any other function in GoogleSheets using Google Finance's data to get the results?

Comment: I think that the core of your question is about asking for recommendations for a real-time stock data source. If this is right this question is off-topic here and it should be reworded and posted to [Quantivative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Rubén Google Finance already reports trading prices in real-time for US stocks.  The "real-time" reference was made to avoid confusion with alternate sources, such as WSJ.com that publish 52-week data hourly.  The reference is now removed.  The question in short is how to make a stock screener in GoogleSheets, preferably using Google Finance's data.

Answer (score 2):

The [`GoogleFinance`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) command retrieves prices for a particular stock, specified as the first argument of the command. In order to receive data for multiple stocks, you need multiple `GoogleFinance` commands, one for each stock.

Possible implementation:

- Column A lists the stocks: GOOG, APPL, MSFT, etc.
- Column B lists today's high, like `B2 =GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"high")`
- Column C lists 26-week high (as explained in [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80983); the  last option from there should be used to get a single-cell result).

Then, on another sheet, you put

```
=Query(Sheet1!A:C,"select * where B=C")
```

or (to get only the stock symbols without prices)

```
=Query(Sheet1!A:C,"select A where B=C")
```

#### Notes

- You'll have to obtain and enter (copy/paste) the list of stocks yourself.
- This is a data-intensive process, especially when many stocks are involved. You will likely find the spreadsheet sluggish, or will encounter an error when a Google server decides you are using too much of their resources.
- A spreadsheet is not a trader's dashboard and should not be used as one.

Comment: Thanks.  Google Finance has a disclaimer per your note.  I'm looking to create the filtered list from the universe of US companies of the day's stocks making new 26-week highs.  I understand from web searches that this sort of stock screen was possible before the Google Finance-specific APIs were made defunct (https://developers.google.com/finance/).  Do you know if there is a way to create Google Finance broad market stock screens using Google Sheets?